# How do I turn lights on & off manually along with home automation?

Tags: home-automation

Need some help regarding HomeAutomation

I was doing my room automate via Arduino with the help of relay , but a little problem I am facing,that when I switched on the light via relay then I cannot turn it off via switch board manually ,the switch is now useless & I have tried two way switch but it's not a better solution.
So please can anyone tell me how to solve this problem so that I can turn lights on manually & automatic too
Thanks

Comment: This question is better suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ because your question's root has nothing to do with Arduino, but everything to do with wiring and switches.

Comment: A relay with both NO and NC contacts could function as one of the two switches in a conventional two-way switch setup, but you need to be very careful when wiring mains circuits - there are real hazards there.  Likely that subject matter belongs on Home Improvement SE, not on Electronics Stack Exchange.

Comment: you can use super caps to record manual offs, keeping the system in sync. if you set it to turn on when powered-on, a flip of the switch (or two) can result in your desired state.

Comment: Thank you so much , I will also add this question to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create something like in the picture, one switch will be the relay.
[image: hotel switch]

Comment: The switch already in place is probably not a three way switch, however it could be switched out for one.

Comment: He said he already tried a two way switch.

Comment: how would the arduino detect the state of the light?

Comment: Yes sir, already did that but any possible way to detect switch is turned on/off ? This will help me to turn the relay state

Comment: the state does not matter in this case, the relay can be either in on or off possition to set the light on, depending on the state of the lightswitch.
You could determine if the light is on or off by measuring current just before the lamp.